# Covert form data to JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<form name = 'test' >
    <input type='text' name = 'login'>
    <input type='email' name = 'email'>
</form>
```

If I use `JSON.serialize($(form)).serializeArray();`
I get `[{"name":"login","value":"a value"},{"name":"email","value":"a email"}]` while I need **`{"login":"a login","email":"a email"}`**. How to do that??

Comment: what if you get rid of the call to .serializeArray()

Comment: What's the use case, generally you'd want `www-url-encoded` data from a form

Comment: Also, where does `JSON.serialize` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `<form>` to `FormData()`, iterate key, value pairs of `FormData` instance, set each key and value to an object property and value

```js
let form = document.forms["test"];

let fd = new FormData(form);

let data = {};

for (let [key, prop] of fd) {
  data[key] = prop;
}

data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<form name='test'>
  <input type='text' name='login' value="a login">
  <input type='email' name='email' value="a email">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the `null` and `2` parameters in `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: @IDunno https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Ah, I will use this more often when debugging, ty! `null` for the replacer filter, and `2` for identation.

Comment: @guest271314 Thank you!

Comment: FYI this may not always work because the `key` is not always unique.  for example: a file input can allow multiple files.  if so, they all have the same key.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this:

```
JSON.stringify($(form).serializeArray().reduce((acc, f) => {
  acc[f.name] = f.value
  return acc
}, {})
```

Comment: `[{"login":""},{"email":""}]` you need to merge this objects to achieve the answer : p

Comment: Nice one !  : ).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, using plain js and `form.elements` as an argument to `Array.reduce`

```js
var d = [].reduce.call(document.forms['test'].elements,(a,b)=>(a[b.name]=b.value,a),{});
var j = JSON.stringify(d, 0, 4);

console.log(j);
```

```html
<form name='test'>
  <input type='text' name='login'>
  <input type='email' name='email'>
</form>
```

Using jQuery

```js
var data = $('form :input').toArray().reduce( (a,b) => (a[b.name]=b.value,a),{})
var json = JSON.stringify(data,0,4);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name='test'>
  <input type='text' name='login'>
  <input type='email' name='email'>
</form>
```

Comment: The first example incorrectly defines `d` but requires `data` (not enough chars difference to edit, though). Otherwise, this works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want javascript object:

```
 let dest = {};
 $( form )
     .serializeArray()
     .map( input => dest[ input.name ] = input.value );
```

And the Json:

```
 console.log( JSON.stringify( dest ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get this

`[{"name":"login","value":"a value"},{"name":"email","value":"a email"}];`

and you need just

```
{"name":"login","value":"a value"}
```

just call the variable by their index

```js
var data = [{"name":"login","value":"a value"},{"name":"email","value":"a email"}];

console.log( data[0] )
```

Answer (score -2):

real quick solution that utilizes .serializeArray() would be:

```
var objArr = JSON.serialize($(form)).serializeArray();
var obj = objArr.pop();
var strJson = JSON.serialize(obj);
```