# ES6 API Fetch Login WebApp

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm asking if my codes are correct. I'm trying to get access from a POST login api. It should have a response from the Website API. My problem is on the Fetch function. It doesn't POST data to the API. It says the email and password is required

```js
function submitInfo(){
let form = document.forms["myForm"];
let fd = new FormData(form);
let data = {};
for (let [key, prop] of fd) {
  data[key] = prop;
}
VALUE = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
console.log(VALUE);


fetch('http://example_website/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: VALUE
})

.then(data => data.json())
.then(data =>  { console.log(data) }) 
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})

}
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="example@gmail.com">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="123">
      </div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit!" onclick="submitInfo();">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: _"Why there is an error in my log called "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input""_ JavaScript at Question is missing closing `}` at `submitInfo` function

Comment: @JaromandaX. So what do I'll change JSON.stringify to?

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah you're right. I missed that closing {};

Comment: See [Covert form data to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45305680/)

Comment: @guest271314. Can you help me with that. The error is now Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized). But my email and password is correct.

Comment: What does `POST` data does server expect?

Comment: @guest271314. Well i have a website API but i can't of course give it to the public since it is still in development mode. BTW, It should expect these phrase "{
    "message": "Invalid credentials",
    "response": false
}"  if the values i inputed is incorrect otherwise {
    "message": "Login successful",
    "response": true,
    "token": token,
    "user": user
}

Comment: _"Well i have a website API but i can't of course give it to the public since it is still in development mode."_ Then you are the webmaster. Only you can resolve the error response from server, yes? `"{ "message": "Invalid credentials", "response": false }"` is not valid `JSON`, double quotes should not be within double quotes.

Comment: @guest271314. I'm sorry that is  incorrect. This is the one {
    "message": "Invalid credentials",
    "response": false
} How would i output these response?

Comment: @Joseph What is "the Website API"?

Comment: @guest271314. It's my website where i put my api. Example is this http://sample.website.com/api.

Comment: Only you can correct the issues at server, unless you include the server code at Question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314. But i'm asking for help on how to output these { "message": "Invalid credentials", "response": false } from the api website

Comment: By _"the api website"_ do you mean a) from browser to server; b) from server to browser; c) both a) and b)?

Comment: @guest271314. B. It should expect these phrase { "message": "Invalid credentials", "response": false }" if the values i inputed is incorrect otherwise  if it is incorrect, it should ouput { "message": "Login successful", "response": true, "token": token, "user": user }

Comment: Have you read previous comment and links? How is b) related to original Question where no server code appears at Question?

Comment: @guest271314. I did

Comment: @guest271314  Response

{
    "message": "Invalid credentials",
    "response": false
}
                        
Failed Response
{
    "message": "Login successful",
    "response": true,
    "token": token,
    "user": user
}
                        
Success Response

Comment: @guest271314. It should output either these two phrases. Thats the only problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting `body` to `JSON.stringify({ "message": "Login successful", "response": true, "token": token, "user": user })`, where `token` and `user` are defined?

Comment: @Joseph Your question is presently not clear.

Comment: @JaromandaX. I already got the problem. The tried to console.log  and the object strings are empty.

Comment: @guest271314. I already got the problem. The tried to console.log and the object strings are empty.

Comment: @JaromandaX. I believe that the problem is when added my input elements. It outputs an empty string when I console.log it. Do you have any idea on how would i retrieve the values as one form. Well you can do this let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm').value but it won't get the values from email and password

Comment: @JaromandaX. Still the values are empty.

Comment: @JaromandaX. Can you check my edited snippet. I believe that my problem is on the fetch function. It doesn't POST to the Login API. Maybe there's an error in my fetch code

Comment: @JaromandaX. The errors are POST http://EXAMPLE_WEBSITE/api/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)  AND Object {message: "Validation failed", errors: Object, response: false}
errors
:
Object
email
:
Array(1)
password
:
Array(1)
__proto__
:
Object
message
:
"Validation failed"
response
:
false
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: @JaromandaX. The email field is required and password field is required. Possibly it doesn't get the data.

Comment: @JaromandaX. Check the edited snippet. It did output in JSON.stringify after i inputed the values

Comment: @JaromandaX. It says message: "Validation failed",…}
errors
:
{email: ["The email field is required."], password: ["The password field is required."]}
message
:
"Validation failed"
response
:
false

Comment: @JaromandaX. Yes. Its output is {
  "email": "example@gmail.com",
  "password": "123"
}

Comment: @JaromandaX. But I think my fetch function is incorrect

Comment: @JaromandaX. My email and password value are not read under the fetch function. The error says email and password is required

Comment: @JaromandaX example@gmail.com and 123 must be read in order to get a response from the server.

Comment: @JaromandaX. So what format that the server side expect in order to read the email and password

Comment: @JaromandaX. Can you check above. Ive added an image.

Comment: @JaromandaX. JSON format. And that image(response) above should output in the console.log

Comment: @JaromandaX. JSON format. And the response(see image above) should output in the console.log

Comment: In that case you're doing something wrong in the server code...

Comment: @JaromandaX. I got it. Check my answer below

Comment: yeah, one of my deleted in frustration comments suggested that header hours ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Just put const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

AND

const myHeaders = new Headers();
 myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

```js
function submitInfo(){
    
    let form = document.forms["myForm"];
    let fd = new FormData(form);
    let data = {};
    for (let [key, prop] of fd) {
      data[key] = prop;
    }
    VALUE = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    console.log(VALUE);

    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    fetch('http://example_website/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default',
        body: VALUE
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data =>  { console.log(data) }) 
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    })
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="example@gmail.com">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="123">
    </div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit!" onclick="submitInfo();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the closing parentheses on your fetch() function. You have fetch(